# How to convert typescript alias path to Jest "moduleNameMapper", when alias is for specific file?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to configure Jest, in a typescript project.

Here we use path alias in tsconfig.json, like this:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@eddystone-shared/*": [ "../shared/*" ],
  "@eddystone-firebase-helpers/*": [ "src/helpers/firebase-helpers/*" ],
  "@eddystone-func-config": ["src/config/config"],
```

So they work like this:

1. References all files in parent directory, i.e.
2. References all files in src sub directory.
3. References one *specific file*.

I have found in Jest github, that the Jest `moduleNameMapper` is the config to use. I have tried converting like this:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@eddystone-shared/(.*)$": "<rootDir>../shared/$1",
  "^@eddystone-firebase-helpers/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/helpers/firebase-helpers/$1",
  "^@eddystone-func-config/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/config/config",
```

But it does not work. The problem is the `@eddystone-func-config`alias. So my question is: How do you create a `moduleNameMapper` entry, for a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is worth to say that [jest-module-name-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-module-name-mapper) package should help. It generates `moduleNameMapper` config automatically based on your `tsconfig.json` content.

As the docs say, the only thing that should be done is to configure `jest.config.js` the following way:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: require('jest-module-name-mapper')(),
};
```

---

As for your config, it seems that `"^@eddystone-func-config/(.*)$"` regex is incorrect and misunderstood: as the function is needed to be imported as `"@eddystone-func-config"`, this name should match the regex but it does not. `/(.*)` is unnecessary since `@eddystone-func-config` is not a directory.